# de Rham Cohomology of Schwarzschild Manifold

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, topology

Let $C^p(M)$ denote the group of closed $p$-forms on the manifold $M$, and $Z^p(M)$ the group of all exact $p$-forms on the manifold $M$. The [de Rham cohomology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology) is given by the quotient,

$$H^p(M)=C^p(M) \, / \, Z^p(M)$$

I am interested in computing the de Rham cohomology of a [Schwarzschild manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric), i.e.

$$H^p\left(\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2\right)$$

Proceeding from the above definition may be arduous, so could one use a [Mayer-Vietoris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer%E2%80%93Vietoris_sequence) approach instead? If so, what is the Mayer-Vietoris sequence for cohomology (rather than homology), and what decomposition of the manifold, if any, can we apply to use Mayer-Vietoris? Otherwise I was hoping to utilize a theorem which expresses the cohomology of a Cartesian product of spaces, as 
$$H^p(\mathbb{S}^2)\quad H^p(\mathbb{R}^2)$$

are well-known cohomologies. Other creative/different approaches to computing the cohomology are certainly welcome and encouraged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is such a theorem about product spaces, it's called the Künneth formula. For de Rham cohomology, $$H^n(Y \times X) \cong \bigoplus_{i+j=n} H^j(X)\otimes H^i(Y).$$
Since the cohomology of $S^n$ and $\mathbb R^n$ are both well known, the calculation is now simple. You can find this theorem in the book by Bott and Tu, *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology*.

You could of course also use a Mayer-Vietoris sequence with $U$ as a spherical cap slightly south of the equator, and $V$ as a spherical cap slightly north of the equator, both extended for all times. Then both $U$ and $V$ have the topology of $\mathbb R^4$ (because a hemisphere has the topology of $\mathbb R^2$) and $U \cap V$ has the topology of $S^1 \times \mathbb R^3$ (because a band around sphere has the topology of $S^1 \times \mathbb R$). Then you need to find the cohomology of $S^1 \times \mathbb R^3$. You can do this also with the Mayer-Vietoris sequence. Bott and Tu use the M-V sequence on $S^1$ as an example, this calculation will be essentially the same.

There's a good reason that the calculation will be essentially the same, namely that $S^1$ is a deformation retract of $S^1 \times \mathbb R^3$. Cohomology is invariant under deformation retracts, so we really just need to know the cohomology of $S^1$. In fact for the original problem of $S^2 \times \mathbb R^2$ has $S^2$ has a deformation retract, so we could have used this from the beginning.

However calculating the cohomology of $S^n$ is rather simple with the M-V sequence. You just need to know it for $S^1$ and then you can proceed by induction.

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I needed! I feel embarrassed now that the problem seems trivial, but I'm just learning about cohomology :)

Comment: I feel embarrassed that I missed an even simpler argument, please see the updated answer. :)

Comment: I'm just wondering in GR, for many manifolds which are solutions to a particular Einstein field equation, all we know about them is their metric, Killing vectors, etc. How can we proceed from that point to a point where we can compute global properties, e.g. cohomology?

Comment: That's a question I've been wondering about myself, you should post it as a question! Maybe some places to start looking could be *Exact Solutions* by Stephani et al. and *The Large-Scale Structure of Space-time* by Hawking and Ellis.

Comment: If you can prove the solution is compact, you could get to the Euler characteristic fairly quickly using the Gauss-Bonnet-Chern theorem. I'll post the question :)

Comment: I'm going to ask a math PhD I know, I'll keep you posted by updating the question on the physics S.E.